# Need advise on SQL query to return active policy records

Tags: sql

I need some advise and ideas on writing a query that returns a count of policies that are in-force, or active, per month over a 12 month period.  I can easily build it for a given month (see simplified example) but was hoping to find a way to avoid using JOIN statements, something more efficient.  There WHERE condition is the part I'm struggling with.

```
select 'January', count(*)
from policies
where effective_date < '1/1/2012'
and expiration_date > '2/1/2012'
```

Suggestions?

Comment: what rdbms you are using? sql server? mysql? oracle? etc.....

Comment: you mean a UNION statement?

Comment: The query could be used against either Oracle or SQL Server.  And yes, sorry, I meant a UNION.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use GROUP BY to aggregate policies based on month

```
SELECT month, count(*) FROM policies WHERE effective_date < '1/1/2012' AND expiration_date > '1/1/2013' GROUP BY month;
```

Comment: That was my first thought too, but it doesn't return the correct record counts.  Example: effective_date='12/12/2012' and expiration_date='6/12/2013', how does the GROUP BY month determine the query needs to count this record for month Jan - Jun?  Won't it skip those months because it can't match the calendar month to the dates in the record?

Comment: The WHERE clause just filters all records out that don't fall into the date range, then proceeds to group the remaining records in the table based on their month. It sounds like every record isn't associated with a single month in your case, rather every record has start and end dates?

Comment: Correct, all have start and end dates, and need to be counted in the months in between.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
datename(m,p.effective_date) as mymonth,

count(*)
from policies p

where effective_date BETWEEN '1 jan 2012' AND '31 dec 2012'
and  expiration_date BETWEEN '1 jan 2012' AND '31 dec 2012'

group by datename(m,p.effective_date)
```

Comment: Not quite, because I would need to count records where the effective and/or expiration dates can fall outside of the desired date range.  BUT, you've given me an idea to use a series of statements in the WHERE clause: (effective_date < '1/1/12' and expiration_date >= '2/1/12') or (effective_date < '2/1/12' and expiration_date >= '3/1/12') ... etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those who took the time and interest in my problem.

I came up with a solution that is probably as efficient as it can get.  I wrote a sub-select statement that sets the date values that I need to report on (pseudo query:

```
select add_months(trunc(sysdate),"month",-12) from dual
union
select add_months(trunc(sysdate),"month",-11) ..
```

and so on), then added that as a stand-alone table to my primary query, which used those dates in the `WHERE` condition and the `GROUP BY`.  Worked like a champ.

Again, my thanks to all who responded and helped me get some different thought processes going.